# Render Content Dynamically from an array map function in React Native functional component and useState

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a functional component to render a simple form with some input elements.

I want to be able to dynamically add input elements when the user click a button.
Im using useState hook and created a onChange arrow func as follows:

```
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState<PlayerModel[]>([
    { id: 0, firstName: "", lastName: "" },
  ]);

  const handleOnAddPlayerPress = () => {
    let newPlayers = players;
    newPlayers.push({ id: newPlayers[newPlayers.length - 1].id + 1, firstName: "", lastName: "" });
    setPlayers(newPlayers);
  }
```

I'm rendering the players using array map function as follows:

```
{players.map((player, index) => {
      return <Input key={index} label={`Player #${player.id}`} />;
    })}
```

Im calling the onChange function when the user clicks the button as follows:

```
<Button
  onPress={handleOnAddPlayerPress}
  type="clear"
  icon={
    <Icon
      raised={true}
      name="user-plus"
      underlayColor="black"
      type="font-awesome"
      reverse
    />
  }
></Button>
```

all together:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Overlay, Input, Button, Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import { PlayerModel } from "../../models/PlayerModel";

export namespace AddNewTournamentForm {
  export interface Props {
    isVisible: boolean;
    onBackdropPress: () => void;
  }
}

export const AddNewTournamentForm = (
  props: AddNewTournamentForm.Props
): JSX.Element => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState<PlayerModel[]>([
    { id: 0, firstName: "", lastName: "" },
  ]);

  const handleOnAddPlayerPress = () => {
    let newPlayers = players;
    newPlayers.push({ id: newPlayers[newPlayers.length - 1].id + 1, firstName: "", lastName: "" });
    setPlayers(newPlayers);
  } 



  return (
    <Overlay {...props} fullScreen>
      <ScrollView>
        ...
        {players.map((player, index) => {
          return <Input key={index} label={`Player #${player.id}`} />;
        })}
        <Button
          onPress={handleOnAddPlayerPress}
          type="clear"
          icon={
            <Icon
              raised={true}
              name="user-plus"
              underlayColor="black"
              type="font-awesome"
              reverse
            />
          }
        ></Button>
        ...
      </ScrollView>
    </Overlay>
  );
};
```

However the layout doesn't seem to be re-rendering itself when a change occur.
Another strange thing is that when I go out of this overlay and go back, only then I see the updated amount of input elements according to the num of players (which is strange because if I go out and in to the Overlay the state should be initiated).

Any suggestion? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const handleOnAddPlayerPress = () => {
    const newPlayers = [...players]; <-- Do this -->
    newPlayers.push({ id: newPlayers[newPlayers.length - 1].id + 1, firstName: "", lastName: "" });
    setPlayers(newPlayers);
}
```

Comment: thanks . Now it does render dynamically. I wonder why? maybe you can explain :). But the state does not reset itself when I go out of this overaly and back in. I would expect the number of players to be 1 again. I come from react.js world. maybe it's a bit different in react-native?

Comment: It only reflects changes on view when reference changes, so doing [...players] this way will change it's reference too so it worked :-) Vote up if it helped thanks :-)